# Read Checkbox checked property from HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an aspx page which renders as below.

```
<div id="div1">
<tr>
<td>SomeTxt</td>
<td><input checked="checked" class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" /></td>
<td>text2</td>
</tr>
</div>
```

Iam trying to read checkbox checked property from javascript :

```
var status = $('#div1 tbody tr:eq(' + tr.rowIndex + ') td:eq(1)').checked;
```

But I am getting undefined.

Comment: Why not simply `$('input[type=checkbox]').eq(index).is(':checked');`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `is(':checked')`

```
var status = $('#div1 input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
var status = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").val();
alert(status);
```

Answer (score 0):

A TD will not have the checked attribute, you must select the input element.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
$("#yourID").is(":checked")
```

Make sure give an ID to your checkbox, not taking it `<tr>`

Answer (score 0):

td:eq(1) will return td and not the input element

```
var status = $('#div1 tbody tr:eq(' + tr.rowIndex + ') td:eq(1)').find("input").get(0).checked;
```

Regards,